# pass a list of personas to child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an object of campaigns which has name and ads properties. Ads properties itself is an object which has list of personas. I want to pass those list of personas to child component(createNewAd). The way i am doing is not working.

Here is what i have done

```
const campaigns = [
  {
    name: 'Magazine Print', // campaign 2
    ads: [
      {
        name: 'GQ Mag Spring', // ad 1
        scores: [46, 75],
        personas: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Vogue Mag Spring', // ad 2
        scores: [56, 87],
        personas: [
          {
            name: '[[Doug - At Home Writer|||personas/121212]]',
            scores: [
              { score: 42, text: '####% overall' },
              {
                score: 81,
                text: '####% top topic [[Coffeehouse Enlightenment|||boards/123456]]'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: '[[David - Marketing Celebrity|||personas/232323]]',
            scores: [
              { score: 68, text: '####% overall' },
              {
                score: 72,
                text: '####% top topic [[Buyer Personas|||boards/234567]]'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: '[[Ellen - Design Trendsetter|||personas/343434]]',
            scores: [
              { score: 48, text: '####% overall' },
              {
                score: 90,
                text: '####% top topic [[Art Exhibits|||boards/345678]]'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: '[[Steve - Gamer Tech Guy|||personas/454545]]',
            scores: [
              { score: 35, text: '####% overall' },
              {
                score: 52,
                text: '####% top topic [[Video Cards|||boards/456789]]'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: '[[Leslie - Grad at First Job|||personas/676767]]',
            scores: [
              { score: 75, text: '####% overall' },
              {
                score: 85,
                text: '####% top topic [[Small Apartment Living|||boards/567890]]'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Time Mag Spring', // ad 3
        scores: [62, 83],
        personas: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Wired Mag Spring', // ad 4
        scores: [66, 74],
        personas: []
      },
    ]
  },

  {
    name: 'TV primetime spots', // campaign 3
    ads: []
  },
];

export default class Campaign extends Component {
  state = {
    adsShow: false,
    personasShow: false,
    open: false
  };


  renderPersonas = personas => {
    return personas && personas.map((persona, i) => {
      if (!persona.length === 0) {
        return persona.map((person, i) => console.log('person', person));
      }
    });
  }

  renderCampaigns = () => {
    return campaigns.map((campaign, i) => {
      return (
        <Collapsible
          key={campaign.name}
          classParentString="campaignsCollapse">
          <div className="Ads">
            <span className="cmpTitle">Ads</span>
            <span className="editCampaign">
              <FaPlusCircle onClick={this.handleClick} />
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="AdsList">
            {this.state.adsShow
              ? <CreateNewAd
                personasClick={this.handlePersonasClick}
                personasShow={this.state.personasShow}
                hideModal={this.hideModal}
                showModal={this.state.open}
                personas={this.renderPersonas(campaign.ads)}
                />
            : null}
            {this.renderAdLists(campaign.ads)}
          </div>
        </Collapsible>
      );
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '10px 20px' }}>
        <h3>Campaigns</h3>
        <div className="campaignsContainer">
          {this.renderCampaigns()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you have an error. right before `export default...` you need to close your campaigns array with `];`

Comment: sorry i erased that accidentally when slackening the campaign objects.

Comment: The way you are doing it will return an array to the childComponent `CreateNewAd`

Comment: I get personas as undefined. I wanted to pass only personas object to `CreateNewAd` component and from there pass to `personas` component and using map i will show the name of personas in a list.

Comment: So as I understand you want to pass all the personas objects under each campaign at one go and in createNewAd you will render them,  is it

Comment: Yes that's what i want. Isn't that the right way? Because i want to show list of personas in another component not in the parent component.

Comment: No thats right, however I was just thinking whether you should be passing down campaign.ads and then in the createNewAdd map over this and create ads. I think that would be better since it will allow you to have more control

Comment: You mean to say pass personas={camapign.ads} as a props to createNewAdd and there apply the map function to the object(props.personas.personas.map()) to render all the personas, right? This way i get an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Some personas array is empty.

Comment: props.personas.map((persona, i) => console.log(persona)) yields folllowing when passing campaign.ads as a props to createNewAd component. `Object {name: "GQ Mag Spring", scores: Array(2), personas: Array(0)}  Object {name: "Vogue Mag Spring", scores: Array(2), personas: Array(5)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass camapign.ads to the CreateNewAd component and then map over inside this component over the Personas prop as

```
  <CreateNewAd
            personasClick={this.handlePersonasClick}
            personasShow={this.state.personasShow}
            hideModal={this.hideModal}
            showModal={this.state.open}
            personas={campaign.ads}
            />
```

And In the CreateNewAd Component

```
 renderPersonas = () => {
    var {personas} = this.props;
    return personas && personas.map((persona, i) => {
        return <div>{persona.personas && persona.personas.map((person, i) => <li>{JSON.stringify(person)}</li>}</div>
    });
  }
```

Comment: `const CreateNewAd = (props) => {
  console.log('personas', props.personas);
  const renderPersonas = props.personas && props.personas.map((persona, i) => {
    return <div>{persona && persona.map((person, i) => <li>{JSON.stringify(person)}</li>)}</div>
  });

  return (` i get persona.map is not a function error

Comment: Check the update, the inned map must be on persona.personas instead of persona

Comment: Glad to have helped :)